# R data.table not preserving factor when applying function by group

Tags: r, data.table

I want to apply a function which returns factors to columns in a data.table. However, I notice that if the function is applied by group, then the results are converted to integers.

```
> d <- data.table(x = rnorm(20), g = c(rep('a', 10), rep('b', 10)))
> d[, not.by.groups := lapply(.SD, function(x) cut(x, 3)), .SDcols = 'x']
> d[, by.groups := lapply(.SD, function(x) cut(x, 3)), .SDcols = 'x', by = 'g']
> class(d$not.by.group)
[1] "factor"
> class(d$by.group)
[1] "integer"
```

Is there a way to keep the grouped results in factors instead of converting it afterwards?

Comment: I certainly did not search for "unexpected behavior"

Comment: The title here is definitely more descriptive than eddi's question about "unexpected behavior". @mnel, considering that the other question doesn't have an accepted answer and that your answer doesn't apply to this question, what's the duplicate protocol?

Comment: @AnandaMahto - Yes, it was a hard dupe to find (and this title *is* more informative), but it is a dupe none the less. I think it really is a `data.table` quirk - similar to the rbindlist issue with factors (perhaps when a solution is found there, it will fix this issue also). That being said, merging factors with potentially different levels does cause the issue and it isn't clear how you would proceed.

Comment: @mnel `rbindlist` doesn't have any issues with factors any longer. Someone should add this as a bug report.